# Raphael Path gets crazy in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, path, raphael

I'm developing a tool to make areas and tripwires and I'm working with Raphael JS. The thing is that I want to build a path dinamically and I think I got it, at least in Chrome, because in Firefox it gets crazy.

What I mean with crazy is that the position of the points do not correspond with the real position of the cursor (and I repeat, only in Firefox).

You have a fiddle I did here.

http://jsfiddle.net/6dd2870b/4/

Any thoughts on why can this be happening?

Thank you in advance.

The javascript code of the fiddle is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    paper = new Raphael(canvas, canvas.height, canvas.width),
    mousedown = false,
    lastX, lastY, path, pathString, pathAux, pointsAux = [];    


$(canvas).mousedown(function (e) {
   var x = e.offsetX,
       y = e.offsetY;

    if (!mousedown) {
        pathString = 'M ' + x + ' ' + y + ' ';
        mousedown = true;
    } else {
        pathString += 'l ' + (x - lastX) + ' ' + (y - lastY) + ' ';
    }

    pointsAux.push({x: x, y: y});

    path = paper.circle(x,y,9);

    path = paper.path(pathString);   

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
});

$(canvas).mousemove(function (e) {

    if (!mousedown) {
       return;
    }

    var x = e.offsetX,
        y = e.offsetY;
    pathAux = pathString +  'l ' + (x - lastX) + ' ' + (y - lastY);
    path.attr('path', pathAux);
});

$('#finish').click(function (e) {

    if ($('#type').val() != 1) {
        pathAux = pathString +  ' z';
        path.attr('path', pathAux);
    } else {
        path.attr('path', pathString);
    }
    mousedown = false;

 });

 $('#cancel').click(function (e) {
     paper.clear();  
     mousedown = false;
  });
```

Comment: Wow that is weird.  I have no idea what's causing it though.

Comment: I know. May it be caused because of the offsetX or offsetY, that is not working properly in firefox? Anyway if tried with layerX and layerY, but still the same.

Comment: Yeah...I don't know what the problem is.  I doubt its the offsets, because the "wrongness" that Firefox is doing seems to be random and arbitrary, sometimes its off by just a little, sometimes by a lot.  And sometimes the line flickers.  Then when I click, the line goes to the right place and the circle the wrong!

Comment: I would just use Raphs own mousemove methods as they pass in the correct coordinates iirc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to test it again in Firefox v.113.0.1 and somehow is currently working.